# How to read key and value in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a object which contains value like this :-  { 23=4,  51=2,  71=5}

```
$scope.obj = { 23=4,  51=2,  71=5};
```

I need to get value of 51,

Output should be = 2;

I have no idea how to find it please help me to find the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a vew attached to that controller?  If you just want to see the value in that view, the use {{obj.51}}. Otherwise, use any of the attributes/directives built into angular.

Comment: Did you try `$scope.obj['51']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please fix the object declaration and use the index.

```js
var obj = { 23:4,  51:2,  71:5};

alert(obj['51']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize your objects properties with `:` not `=`.

```
$scope.obj = { 23:4,  51:2,  71:5};
```

You can get them with the following code:

```
$scope.obj[51]
```

However I would advice you **not to use numbers** as properties. Use strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Peter's answer: since me as another developer has no reference of what 23 or 51 corresponds to you could use an enumeration to index the values and a freeze to make it immutable;

```
var ColorEnum = Object.freeze({AwesomeValue1: 23, AwesomeValue2: 51,     AwesomeValue3: 71});
```

Where awesomeValue is actually some variable name providing more information ['ErrorState', 'AnswerToProblem5', 'LebronJames', etc...]

Then you could do:

```
$scope.obj[ColorEnum.AwesomeValue1];
```

Output = 4

The little extra work goes a long way in maintainability of bigger projects